# Here SDK flutter does not show places image. Always returns no data for images

Tags: here-api

I am new to "Here" and I am using Here SDK Flutter 4.3.3.0. I want to fetch/search for places and get the Place's Photos/Image and or Place's Logo if the place is a business/company.

The place images `place.details.internalimages` are always empty when I search for any place. I tried for different countries like "Chipotle" a restaurant near Las Vegas, a restaurant in Canda, and a Shopping mall in India. All of these return 0 (zero) images. Does, Here API support to get places photos like Google Places or TomTom API?

Looks like this API has a method to get WebImage List but does not contain any data at all. Please advise, If I need to use any other method to get Place's photos.

Another question is, is there a way to get a company logo, if the place I am searching for is a business/company like Restaurant, Store, etc.

Below is the code, I use in my Flutter application. Note, I am able to get other field values like title, address, etc.

```
TextQuery textQuery = TextQuery.withAreaCenterInCountries('some partial place name', geoCoordinates, countryCodes);

searchEngine.suggest(textQuery, searchOptions, onHereSearchSuggestionCompleted);
```

In `onHereSearchSuggestionCompleted` functions, I have the following code:

```
if(suggestions.length > 0){
      print('explore - onHereSearchSuggestionCompleted - suggestions count > 0');

      for (Suggestion suggestion in suggestions) {
        print('onHereSearchSuggestionCompleted - current count = ${(suggestions.indexOf(suggestion) + 1)}');
        print('onHereSearchSuggestionCompleted - suggestion title =  ${suggestion.title}');
        print('onHereSearchSuggestionCompleted - place id =  ${suggestion.place.id}');
        print('onHereSearchSuggestionCompleted - place title =  ${suggestion.place.title}');
        print('onHereSearchSuggestionCompleted - place address =  ${suggestion.place.address.addressText}');
        print('onHereSearchSuggestionCompleted - place img length =  ${suggestion.place.details.internalimages.length}');
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. we indeed find this as a problem while replicating the use case. a case has been raised to work upon on this bug to our engineering team. will update you as soon as possible over this.

Comment: Thanks, please let me know earliest as soon as this issue is fixed. I am eagerly waiting for this feature. Meanwhile, Is there any alternative HERE API that I could use to get places photos? Please direct me to that documentation URL in HERE site.

Comment: Out of curiosity, just checking, is there any tentative timeline that this fix will be available like in weeks or months

Answer (score 0):

Please note, you have been able to see this functionality being exposed in flutter SDK due to a bug exposing internal methods in flutter. In general this functionality is not yet public (not in native android and iOS).

We plan to expose this functionality soon, however even when we do, only certain eligible customers would have access to the image content. There should be contractual agreement to be able to see this functionality

Comment: Thanks for the details. How to get image content, please provide pricing details, so I could work towards the agreement or please direct me to appropriate resource/team through which I can get access to image content.

Comment: I reached to HERE based on your answer about the contractual agreement and received a call from HERE representative today. I was told this is a technical issue and there is no additional pricing required to access places images. Please advise.